# PostgreSQL replication options

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-extensions

community!
I am wondering if there are any new extensions/solutions which can replicate not the entire PG cluster but by database?
Logical replication is not an option.
For example, I want my primary database "test" to exist on the secondary server in two incarnations - "testreplica1" and "testreplica2" to be able to promote the first one to do smth with it meanwhile the second one would still be up-to-date with production

Comment: Logical replication is _exactly_ the option; why are you saying it's not?

Comment: If you dismiss the obvious solution without giving a reason, why won't you summarily dismiss any other options we offer without reason?

Comment: @mustaccio, a lot of ddl changes

Comment: Well, pglogical can replicate DDL, can't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [PostgreSQL: High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication: Comparison of Different Solutions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/different-replication-solutions.html).  In summary, the following solutions can provide for per-database and per-table replication: *i*, logical solutions (e.g., built-in and pglogical), *ii*, trigger-based solutions (e.g., Slony-I and Londiste), and, *iii*, certain multimaster replication (e.g., Bucardo) can be configured to provide per-database/per-table replication, as well as, *iv*, certain proxy solutions (PgBouncer).

For their availability, integrity, granularity, manageability, and portability benefits, Slony-I and pglogical are both fine solutions, the former exposing real-time internals that have proven useful for monitoring and diagnostics *and* the later natively implementing bi-directional replication (though, Slony-I can facilitate a bi-directional architecture using partitions and/or per-site tables for writes and views for reads, for example).

*Note: Whereas I have far more experience with Slony-I, which certainly provides for DDL (and all other statement) replication (and includes "real-time" sequence state replication), I do believe pglogical too replicates most DDL, though with some exceptions.*